# Webpack: How do I override package.json main field?

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json

How can I override the main field of package.json like in bower?

```
"overrides": {
  "highcharts": {
    "main": "highcharts.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating an alias with the same name as the module in your Webpack config.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "highcharts": path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/file")
        }
    },
    ...
};
```