# npm - package.json override main field

Tags: npm, webpack, package.json

I use some npm packages in my project. Two of them have the wrong `main`-field. Is it possible to override them?

I use webpack. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989956/how-to-override-package-json-main-field).

This works for the main field but I also need a css-file from the same package. I refer it with `~package/css/style.css` in my `index.scss` file. With the solution above it resolves the path with `path/to/main.js/css/style.css` (with main.js) instead of `path/to/css/style.css` (without main.js).

I could refer it directly `../node_modules/path/to/css/style.css` but I think thats ugly.

So is there an other solution with webpack or npm to override this main field?

-- EDIT --

I use `bootstrap-treeview` as package. I refer it in `index.scss` like so 
`@import '~bootstrap-treeview/src/css/bootstrap-treeview.css';`. This works.

When I add `'bootstrap-treeview': path.join(_path, 'node_modules', 'bootstrap-treeview', 'src', 'js', 'bootstrap-treeview.js')` as alias in webpack `import 'bootstrap-treeview';` works but the css not (as describes above).

-- EDIT 2 --

webpack.conf.js:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['', '.js'],
  modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  alias: {
    // bootstrap-treeview alias
    'bootstrap-treeview': path.join(_path, 'node_modules', 'bootstrap-treeview', 'src', 'js', 'bootstrap-treeview.js')
  }
},
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader?sourceMap',
        'postcss-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true
    }
  ]
}
```

index.scss see above.

Error with bootstrap-treeview alias:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /home/ekf/develop/generator-angular-webpack/node_modules/bootstrap-treeview/src/js/bootstrap-treeview.js/src/css/bootstrap-treeview.css in ...
```

Error without alias:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'bootstrap-treeview' in ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you are loading `.scss` files with Webpack? Could you post the code where you are referencing `index.scss` and `style.css`?

Comment: With `~package/css/style.css` it works. As soon as I add the "alias" to the webpack resolve field, it resolves it as described.

Comment: In `bower.json` there is a `overrides`-field for exact that purpose. Is there any similar in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

just in case

webpack scss loader config

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And which loader should I use to load the `css` and `scss` from `node_modules`? It returns `Unexpected token` error.

Comment: "style-loader", "css-loader, "sass-loader" npm packages

Comment: I mean when I exclude `node_modules` then the css files inside it wont load with "style-loader", "css-loader, "sass-loader". It returns `Unexpected token` because there is no loader defined for 'css in node_modules'.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your alias points directly to the JS file, instead of pointing to the common ancestor of both the JS and the CSS.  It's nice and convenient to be able to `import Treeview from "bootstrap-treeview"` but it leads to the problem you're describing.

Instead, you could specify a higher level alias:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    // bootstrap-treeview alias
    'bootstrap-treeview': path.join(_path, 'node_modules', 'bootstrap-treeview', 'src')
  }
},
```

and get the JS as `import Treeview from "boostrap-treeview/js/bootstrap-treeview.js"`.  This allows you to get the CSS as `require("bootstrap-treeview/css/bootstrap-treeview.css")`.

You might be able to get clever about it and tell Webpack to look for CSS files in `~/css/` and JS files in `~/js/` but that would be adding more magic for (IMHO) little gain.