# Laravel 5.5 Webpack dependency was not found

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

Related SO question: [npm - package.json override main field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38610824/npm-package-json-override-main-field/38612717) (I tried to do something like this using the  `webpack.mix.js` but it didn't work).

I have a Laravel 5.5 application with `npm v5.6.0` and `node v9.4.0` (I'm thinking that this maybe is an npm/node version issue, but I don't have an environment to test with older versions ATM). Everything is working fine and I'm working this app for a while now and I've installed some node modules and used `bootstrap.js` and `app.js` to `require/import` npm modules, but it seems there is a problem with the [`bootstrap-treeview`](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview); I've spent more than 2 hours to try and make webpack compile with this module with no luck; I always get that error after `npm run dev`:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>
> This dependency was not found:
>
> - bootstrap-treeview in ./resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js

I tried to use both `require` and `import` inside `bootstrap.js` and I have even tried an other available module `webpack-bootstrap-treeview` which it seems that it doesn't have `bower` dependency:

```
//import "~/node_modules/bootstrap-treeview";
//require("bootstrap-treeview");
//import "bootstrap-treeview";
//import "~/node_modules/webpack-bootstrap-treeview";
//require("webpack-bootstrap-treeview");
import "webpack-bootstrap-treeview";
```

bootstrap-treeview: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-treeview

webpack-bootstrap-treeview: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bootstrap-treeview

[image: Laravel Webpack Run Dev Error]

I know I can just use `laravel-mix` to compile the js files directly to the `app.js` and I will probably do, but I want to have my modules organized and I'd like to find the culprit on this issue.

**EDIT**

I've also tried to delete the `node_modules` directory then `npm install` and even `npm cache clear`, nothing worked for the webpack to compile without that error.

Comment: Are you sure that the files exist that you are trying to compile? Seems like a missing file.

Comment: @killstreet Of course all the files exist. Both `bootstrap-treeview` and `webpack-bootstrap-treeview` are installed with `npm install --save` under the application root directory and I can see both directories when I browse to `node_modules` directory. The difference between those two modules is that the webpack versions does not require `bower` to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are some misnamed files.  Renaming the bootstrap-treeview files in node_modules\bootstrap-treeview-2\dist to bootstrap-treeview-2 allows webpack to successfully complete. Oh, and I installed the bootstrap-treeview-2 package because bootstrap-treeview has been archived.